# Adding overflow menu in actionbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I want to display overflow menu in android actionbar.
In all device i need same design app name at left side of actionbar and overflow icon at right side with menu in it.
Currently when i run app menu are showing on clicking of menu icon.
I just want to show menu like attached image-
[image]

below is my code inside menu.xml -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_red"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/news"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_green"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/online_test"/>
```

how to show menu in such way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_red"
            android:title="red"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_green"
            android:title="green"/>
    </menu>

</item>
```

this worked for me maybe work for you too